# Using one form input button to submit two values to Flask-SQLAlchemy for query?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

It was hard to even figure out how to title this question properly.  Anyway, say I have a HTML input form that contains two text input fields but one submit button like so:

```
<form action="/search_results" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Inventory Search:</legend>
    Search by Item Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="user_item" placeholder="tiger cowrie"><br>
    Search by Item Price:<br>
    <input type="text" name="user_price" placeholder="1.99"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the form action corresponds to my Flask main.py file:

```
@app.route('/search_results', methods = ['POST'])
def item_search():
    user_search = request.form['user_item']
    results = Inventory.query.filter_by(item_name = user_search)
    return render_template("search_results.html", results = Inventory.query.filter_by(item_name = user_search).all())
```

Currently, I'm only using the input box `"user_item"` to perform the SQLAlchemy query.  But what if I wanted to query by using both the `request.form['user_item']` AND `request.form['user_price']`?  I can't quite figure out how I'm supposed to pass two variables with only one input button.

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel silly for not seeing this earlier.  I just created another variable and assigned it to user.price. That way I can simply query both variables as I see fit.

I did figure out how to query them both. You simply have to filter both variables and use a comma between them. But damned if I can figure out OR. Even trying the or_ method I cant get it to work.